# How to implement scripting engine (Jython) into Java?

Tags: java, scripting, jython

How does one go about implementing a scripting engine (I'm thinking Jython) into Java?

I've never done this before, so one major question that I have is; how does the scripting engine know what function calls or fields are available to it?

Is there a simple tutorial to follow on implementing jython into a game? A book possibly?

Comment: Found my answer at Jython documentation, and the integration is seemless! Very amused by this!

Comment: Would you be so kind and help the community (and future googlers) by providing a brief explanation as an answer?

Comment: . could you please let us know how can this be done ..

Answer (score 1):

If you have jython.jar in your path you can start a [PythonInterpreter](http://jython.org/javadoc/index.html), which can execute and compile strings and files and from which you can get python objects (Strings, Integers, Objects, Functions).

Answer (score 0):

I created a Java interface and implemented that java interface using python. That way when you get the python class back as a java instance you can type cast it to the interface and know what methods are available. `__call__` and `__tojava__` are the jython methods to get an instance back from a python implementation.

The Jython Book has a pretty good example and tutorial on how to do this.

http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonAndJavaIntegration.html#using-jython-within-java-applications